# Regex remove alphanumeric but keep parenthesis and spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`var string = 'Size? [Small] Color? [Blue]'`

I want to remove all `non alphanumeric` but keep `spaces` and `[]`

The end string would be

`'Size [Small] Color [Blue]'`

I tried the \W like this:

`string = string.replace(/\W/g, '')`

But that gets rid of the spaces and the `[]`

I'm not sure how to exclude and include items in a regular expression?

Comment: You may use: [`string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \[\]]+/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/kCPXb5/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would whitelist rather than blacklist the characters you want:

```
string.replace(/[^\w[\] ]/g, '');
```

Comment: This will leave underscores if present in input.

Comment: @anubhava good point; if that's undesired then using the `a-z\d` will work with `i`, or `[^\p{Letter}\p{Number} [\]]` if unicode property escapes are available.

Answer (score 3):

`\W` matches all non-word characters.

To match all non alpha-numerals except space, `[` and `]` you should use a negated character class:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \[\]]/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kCPXb5/1/)

**Code:**

```js
let string = 'Size? [Small] Color? [Blue]';

string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \[\]]+/g, '') 

console.log( string );
//=> Size [Small] Color [Blue]
```